# ChartControl - How to plot a line on X Axis (x - fixed coordinate, y - infinity)

Tags: microsoft-chart-controls

I'm developing a C# winforms application in which I want to plot lines on X axis such that the X coordinate is a fixed value, but there is no Y coordinate specified.
Something like this:[image]

Can this be done?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Stripline](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datavisualization.charting.stripline(v=vs.110).aspx) did the trick!

Here's the code:

```
public Series series1 = new Series
    {
        Name = "Series1",
        Color = Color.Black,
        IsVisibleInLegend = false,
        ChartType = SeriesChartType.Line,
        BorderWidth = 0,
        XValueType = ChartValueType.Double,
        YValueType = ChartValueType.Double
    };

    public StripLine startPositionLine = new StripLine
    {
        BorderColor = Color.Red,
        BorderWidth = 2,
        IntervalOffset = 7
    };

    public StripLine endPositionLine = new StripLine
    {
        BorderColor = Color.Blue,
        BorderWidth = 2,
        IntervalOffset = 11
    };

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        chart1.Series.Clear();

        chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.Minimum = 0;
        chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.Interval = 1;

        //Apparently some series with some points have to be present on the chart before the striplines get displayed
        series1.Points.AddXY(0, 0);
        series1.Points.AddXY(10, 0);

        chart1.Series.Add(series1);

        chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.StripLines.Add(startPositionLine);
        chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.StripLines.Add(endPositionLine);

        chart1.Invalidate();
    }
```

And here's how the striplines are plotted:
[image]

One thing I need to check is whether or not a series needs to be plotted first before a stripline can be plotted.